# How to stop recording audio from url?

Tags: android, inputstream, audio-recording

I am recording a streaming radio from a url on Android device using below code:

```
    val data = ByteArray(1024)
            var total: Long = 0
            var count = 0
            startSec = System.currentTimeMillis()
            while (!isCancelled) {

               count = inputStream!!.read(data)
                if (count == -1)
                    break
                total += count
                fileOutputStream!!.write(data, 0, count)
            }

            inputStream!!.close()
            fileOutputStream!!.flush()
            fileOutputStream!!.close()
```

This works great but I am not able to stop the recording at the exact spot when a button is pressed. I have used a flag to stop the recording but still 3-6 min of extra recording is done. Please let me know how to stop at exactly same point.

Comment: are sure when you press the button isCancel variable actually changes? 
sometimes threading creates this issues

Comment: yes I have checked the same.